How to use std::bit_cast on an array pointer type argument
Is it possible to pass address of the first element of an array as argument to std::bit_cast.
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << ", " << e << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    char arr[20]{};
    // arr is filled with some data
    A a = std::bit_cast<A>(arr);
    a.print();

    const char* arrp = arr;
    // doesn't compile
    A b = std::bit_cast<A>(arrp);
    b.print();
}

Error
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:23:27: error: no matching function for call to 'bit_cast<A>(const char*&)'
   23 |     A b = std::bit_cast<A>(arrp);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit:81:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _To, class _From> constexpr _To std::bit_cast(const _From&) requires  sizeof (_To) == sizeof (_From) && __is_trivially_copyable(_To) && __is_trivially_copyable(_From)'
   81 |     bit_cast(const _From& __from) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit:81:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit:81:5: note: constraints not satisfied
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit: In substitution of 'template<class _To, class _From> constexpr _To std::bit_cast(const _From&) requires  sizeof (_To) == sizeof (_From) && __is_trivially_copyable(_To) && __is_trivially_copyable(_From) [with _To = A; _From = const char*]':
<source>:23:27:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit:81:5:   required by the constraints of 'template<class _To, class _From> constexpr _To std::bit_cast(const _From&) requires  sizeof (_To) == sizeof (_From) && __is_trivially_copyable(_To) && __is_trivially_copyable(_From)'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bit:83:27: note: the expression 'sizeof (_To) == sizeof (_From) [with _To = A; _From = const char*]' evaluated to 'false'
   83 |     requires (sizeof(_To) == sizeof(_From))
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1


Pointers are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers. There is no difference between a thing that is the first element of an array, and one that isn't.

@molbdnilo understood. If I have an array of bytes std::vector<char> which I want to bit_cast to some type, how do I do that. Does std::bit_cast have a specialization for std::vector? b'coz I think it has got specialization for an array type

@Harry Use the old-school method; memcpy.

Arrays are not pointers. std::bit_cast<A>(arr); is correct.
arr is passed by reference, and because std::bit_cast has a const From& parameter, From deduces to char[20] and you're effectively passing const char(&)[20], i.e. "reference to array of 20 const char".
This is not the same as passing a pointer.
On the other hand, std::bit_cast<A>(arrp); attempts to bit-cast a pointer (with size 8, presumably) to an A (with size 20, presumably), and you cannot bit-cast between differently sized types.
The better approach here is to do type punning through std::memcpy, which works because A is trivially copyable and implicit-lifetime:
const char* arrp = arr;

A b;
std::memcpy(&b, arrp, sizeof(b));
b.print();

See also What is the modern, correct way to do type punning in C++?

like in functions when passed an array name as argument, it gets decayed to a pointer. So, what happens in case of std::bit_cast?

Arrays can be passed by reference; you get a reference to an array, not a pointer. std::bit_cast has a const From& parameter.

An array can decay to a pointer in some context but in this, it doesn’t. Instead, it remains as an array and std::bit_cast can take its address and treat it as a contiguous block of memory. [1]
In the second case, arrp is a pointer. When you pass arrp to std::bit_cast, you’re passing a pointer, not a block of memory. This is an important distinction. If you look at the suggested possible implementation of std::bit_cast [cppreference] according to cppreference, it suggests that the address of the function argument will eventually be taken and passed as an argument to std::memcpy:
template<class To, class From>
std::enable_if_t<
    sizeof(To) == sizeof(From) &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<From> &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<To>,
    To>
// constexpr support needs compiler magic
bit_cast(const From& src) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<To>,
        "This implementation additionally requires "
        "destination type to be trivially constructible");
 
    To dst;
    std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(To));
    return dst;
}
See the problem now? The pointer argument is unexpected because it will still take the address of src. You can use the core of the implementation directly without all the checks.
Obligatory nit: You do realize that you are going really low level now and a bunch of stuff are unreliable. For example, int might not be exactly 32 bits. The assertion that sizeof struct A == sizeof char arr[20] is not guaranteed on all implementations.

[1] It does not decay because it is passed by const&
